# How to map ko.observable child object to jquery grid

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-plugins, jqxgrid

I have been trying for several days, searching, trying, debugging, but I'm unable to solve the followin problem:

Please see 1 object from a knocout observable array :

```
Code: "CT001"
Description: "CT Neck"
Duration: 15
IsActive: true
IsSchedulingRequired: true
ModalityType: Object
             Code: "CT"
             Name: null
__proto__: ObjectStudyID: 2
```

I'm trying to bind the whole object (including the child object) to a jquery grid using:

```
self.studies = ko.observableArray();

var studyGridSource = {
        localdata: self.studies,
        datatype: "observablearray"
    }

var studiesDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(studyGridSource);

$('#studiesGrid').jqxGrid({
        source: studiesDataAdapter,
        columns: [
            { text: "Description", datafield: 'Description' },
            { text: 'Duration', datafield: 'Duration' },
            { text: 'Code', map: 'ModalityType>Code' },
        ]
    });
```

When populating the grid it nicely shows Description and Duration, however the Code column stays empty.

I see in the debugger of google chrome that I have the complete object.

Anybody any tips?

Comment: Don't think it's Knockout related: I can [reproduce this behavior without KO](http://jsfiddle.net/x5jdu7xv/). I'm unfamiliar with jqxGrid, but if I expand "Columns" in [the appropriate docs](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-api.htm) I don't see it having a `map` property. Perhaps you need something like a DataSource to do what you want?

Comment: Well, I have been doing some further investigation here :http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdataadapter/jquery-data-adapter.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

Please see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x5jdu7xv/6/

```
self.studies = [
{
    Description: "CT Neck",
    Duration: 15,
    ModalityType: { Code: "CT", Name: null }
}
];

var studyGridSource = {
localdata: self.studies,
datafields: [
    { name: "Description", datafield: 'Description' }, 
    { name: 'Duration', datafield: 'Duration' }, 
    { name: 'Code', map: 'ModalityType>Code' }, 
    ]
};

var studiesDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(studyGridSource);

$('#studiesGrid').jqxGrid({
source: studiesDataAdapter,columns: [
    { text: "Description", datafield: 'Description' }, 
    { text: 'Duration', datafield: 'Duration' }, 
    { text: 'Code', datafield: 'Code' }, 
]

});
```

Comment: The only drawback is that, when you bind to the selected row with for example a button to get the selected row, you will lose you original json object definition, i.o.w you will only have a flat object without the child objects. If anybody has an idea how to restore it to the original json object, I would be happy to hear idea's.

Comment: For those intrestested:buttonclick: function(row) {
    var originalRowData = studiesDataAdapter.loadedData[row];
    console.log(originalRowData);
}